# Is there an easy way to build a PyPi package that uses deprecated Numpy API in C?

Tags: numpy, scipy, package, pypi, distutils

I'm trying to build [`K-Means 2`](https://github.com/obachem/kmc2), and have been trying to run the below `setup.py` file using `python setup.py install`, `pip install kmc2`, and `pip install .` from the source package. I have Numpy version 1.2X (higher than 1.7), but I am not sure how to include the `#define X` statements that others online as well as the warning have suggested when compiling the package setup C files.

```
"Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION"
```

```py
import numpy as np
from setuptools import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('kmc2', sources=['kmc2.c'], extra_compile_args=['-O3'])
setup(
    install_requires=["numpy", "scipy", "scikit-learn", "nose"],
    ext_modules=[module1],
    include_dirs=[".",np.get_include() ])
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I have tried changing the sources to `kmc2.pyx` instead. Furthermore, I tried adding the macros as an option to the `Extension()` object using `define_macros=[("NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API", "NPY_1_7_API_VERSION")]`, but this did not work either.

Trying to install Numpy 1.7 using `pip` also results in the same `legacy-install-error` and can't be built.

I am thinking the solution may come from editing the Numpy internal `setup.py` build file.